# Cut/copy/paste alternate cell rows onto the next column & delete empty rows after

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

I have challenges in highlighting/copying alternate rows in one column and pasting it to the next column and aligned.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Following code assumes you have two separate tabs, SRC and DST and the range of data starts in the first cell. Will do all in a single step:

```
Public Sub CopyAlternate()
Dim i As Long

i = 2

While Len(Sheets("SRC").Cells(i, 1).Value) > 0
    Sheets("DST").Cells(i / 2 + 1, 1).Value = Sheets("SRC").Cells(i, 1).Value
    Sheets("DST").Cells(i / 2 + 1, 2).Value = Sheets("SRC").Cells(i + 1, 1).Value
    i = i + 2
Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer and this is helpful however, the data is actually on the same tab, and its just a matter of cutting/copying some cells on its next column then deleting the empty cells (rows) it left.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can take this code and adjust it to taste:

```
Sub alternate()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim n As Integer

    i = 0
    j = 0
    n = 0

    With ActiveSheet        
        For Each c In .Range("A4:A16")
            .Cells(20 + j, 1 + i).Value = c.Value
            If n = 0 Or n Mod 2 = 0 Then
                i = 1
                j = j
            Else
                i = 0
                j = j + 1
            End If
            n = n + 1
        Next c
    End With    
End Sub
```

This worked for me when rebuilding your example with letters (for faster checking).
[image]